# File Open/Save Dialog

Tags: c#

I'm trying to browse a directory in File Open/Save dialog. I could able to get the handle of common dialog as well as its control window. But I don't know how to provide a filename and click the Save/Open button to Save/Open a file. I couldn't find the SendMessage parameters needed to perform these actions. Any suggestions?

Comment: My problem has been solved...

Comment: What i have done here
CustomViewAPI.Win32.SendMessage(handleWnd, CommonConst.WM_SETTEXT, this.CurrentSearchPath.Length, this.CurrentSearchPath);

CustomViewAPI.Win32.SendMessage((IntPtr)handleWnd, CommonConst.WM_SETFOCUS, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
CustomViewAPI.Win32.SendMessage((IntPtr)handleWnd, CommonConst.WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)CommonConst.VK_RETURN, IntPtr.Zero);
CustomViewAPI.Win32.SendInput(1, ref structInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new CommonStruct.INPUT()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to control a different application, and that's why you are getting the handle of the window etc.

If that's the case, you could use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to send Alt-N to select the name field, then the filename, then Alt-S to hit save.

If you are just trying to use an Open or Save dialog in your own program, then you should use the built-in OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog components.

Comment: I am using my own Custom View to show the files and folders and also using a search box to jump to a specific folder. In that case How to send a message to File Open/Save dialog to enforce it to change the current displayed folder. e.g. If the window is currently displaying "C:\", I want an API (or any piece of code) to enforce that window to change the current folder to "D:\"

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using SendMessage? Why not use the built in `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` classes?

See here for details about `OpenFileDialog`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

Comment: I am using my own Custom View to show the files and folders and also using a search box to jump to a specific folder. In that case How to send a message to File Open/Save dialog to enforce it to change the current displayed folder.

e.g. If the window is currently displaying "C:\", I want an API (or any piece of code) to enforce that window to change the current folder to "D:\".

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. My first suggestion would be to close the dialog and then reopen it with a new `InitialDirectory`, but if that's not a viable solution I'd look at subclassing the `FileDialog` class and see if you can add that functionality that way.

Answer (score 0):

What actions are you trying to do? You have the post tagged as C#, but I can't think of a reason to get the hwnds and use SendMessage.

For example, in the WPF OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog you can set the property FileName (or FileNames) or set the InitialDirectory.

Comment: I am using my own Custom View to show the files and folders and also using a search box to jump to a specific folder. In that case How to send a message to File Open/Save dialog to enforce it to change the current displayed folder.


e.g. If the window is currently displaying "C:\", I want an API (or any piece of code) to enforce that window to change the current folder to "D:\".